# Book where humans are considered extremely strong and aliens come to Earth looking for help

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I have been looking for a book for years, but have very little detail about it. I don't know title or author.

The main story line is aliens come to Earth for help in a war and humans have super strength compared to other alien races. I vaguely remember there is a scene where an alien first appears to a random fisherman, who freaks out and hits it, sending it flying.

Comment: How many years? When did you read it? Do you remember any other plot details?

Comment: unfortunately I don't. This was ages ago, a good 15 years at least.

Comment: Possible [A Call To Arms](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/45752/5930).  If so, please confirm so we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The memory is just a blur but this all seems to add up. Much obliged, now the eager wait for it to arrive.

Comment: see OP confirmation comment above

Answer (score 7):

This is likely [A Call to Arms](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/171535.A_Call_to_Arms) by Alan Dean Foster.

> The Amplitur searched the universe for intelligent species to join
>   them in the Amplitur Purpose. But the Weave, a union of races, fought
>   for thousands of years to stay independent. Now a Weave scouting party
>   had discovered Earth, and humanity had to pick sides, for the Amplitur
>   were close behind.

A black fisherman is one of the book's recurring characters;

> *”For us to properly determine if you can be of real assistance to us
>   will involve a journey outside your own solar system. You will be well
>   treated, properly cared for, and amply supplied upon your safe return
>   home with the gold you value so highly. No harm will come to you, and
>   you will have experienced things your kind has not yet imagined.”
>   Showing how much he had learned, he added with visible effort, ”We
>   would not force any of you to do this against your will. If you choose
>   not to accompany us, you may depart whenever you wish.” **The fisherman
>   picked up his simple pack and strode wordlessly forward, followed by
>   the Australian students and the old woman.** The others followed en
>   masse. Will inhaled deeply, took a last look at the familiar night
>   sky, put the keys to the van on the driver’s seat, and strode up the
>   ramp into the hovering transport.*

Comment: I suspect the OP mistakenly remembered Will as being a fisherman because he was in a boat when he first encountered the aliens.  Although the fact that there *was* a minor character who was a fisherman might have helped I suppose.

Comment: I suspect you may be right. Holding thumbs this is it.